# Cannot get view to update with downloaded JSON

Tags: swiftui

I am stuck at the simplest place right now.. I'm making a network request and just want the view to be updated once the JSON is received..

And I verified that:

- JSON is valid
- Valid response received (verified in print statement)

I've done this about 50 times and don't know why I'm stuck at this point.

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @StateObject var nm = NetworkManager()
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            ScrollView {
                HStack {
                    ForEach(nm.articles, id: \.hashValue) { article in
                        Text("Hello")
                    }
                }.task {
                    do {
                        try await NetworkManager().getAllArticles(for: "mario")
                    } catch { print(error) }
            }
            }
                
            Spacer()
                
        }
    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}


    import SwiftUI

final class NetworkManager: ObservableObject {
    @Published var newsItem: News?
    @Published var articles: [Article] = []
    
    private let apiKey = ""//removed
    
    private var baseUrlString: String {
        "https://newsapi.org/v2/"
    }
    
    func getAllArticles(for searchItem: String) async throws {
        let url = URL(string: baseUrlString + "everything?q=\(searchItem)&apiKey=\(apiKey)")!
        let (data, _) = try await URLSession.shared.data(from: url)
       
        let news = try JSONDecoder().decode(News.self, from: data)
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            self.newsItem = news
            self.articles = self.newsItem!.articles
        }
    }
 
    
}

struct News: Codable {
    var totalResults: Int?
    let articles: [Article]
}

struct Article: Codable, Hashable {
    let author: String?
    let title: String
    let description: String
    let url: String
    let urlToImage: String?
    let publishedAt: String
    let content: String
}
```

Edit: removed apiKey

Comment: I think you could have just used this: "try await nm.getAllArticles(for: "mario")"

Comment: @workingdog yes, it’s unclear why I created the class for the init and then didn’t use it later in code.

Comment: I think what you did is the wright approach. Let the UI do the UI and let the NetworkManager do the network fetching. API requests code definitely does not belongs in the UI code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`getAllArticles()` is view-related, which means you should probably implement this function inside the `View` instead of `ObservableObject`.

```swift
struct ContentView: View {
    @StateObject var nm = NetworkManager()
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            ScrollView {
                VStack {
                    ForEach(nm.articles, id: \.hashValue) { article in
                        Text("Hello")
                    }
                }.task {
                    do {
                        try await getAllArticles(for: "mario")
                    } catch { print(error) }
                }
            }
                
            Spacer()
                
        }
        .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity)
    }
}

extension ContentView {
    func getAllArticles(for searchItem: String) async throws {
        let url = URL(string: nm.baseUrlString + "everything?q=\(searchItem)&apiKey=\(NetworkManager.apiKey)")!
        let (data, _) = try await URLSession.shared.data(from: url)
       
        let news = try JSONDecoder().decode(News.self, from: data)
        // Not necessary
        // DispatchQueue.main.async {
            nm.newsItem = news
            nm.articles = nm.newsItem!.articles
        // }
    }
}

final class NetworkManager: ObservableObject {
    @Published var newsItem: News?
    @Published var articles: [Article] = []
    
    static let apiKey = "YOUR_API_KEY"
    
    var baseUrlString: String {
        "https://newsapi.org/v2/"
    }
}
```

Comment: Well that definitely worked, but help me understand.. I thought that was the very purpose of a viewModel.. to abstract away from the view what the view doesn't need to know..